# How to programatically select multiple disparate cells to copy to clipboard and then manually paste to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

As a simple example, I have to select every 22nd cell in a column until I reach an empty cell.  I need to be able to copy all of those cells to the clipboard to be pasted into another spreadsheet.  I can select each cell properly, but don't know how to gather them in an object to be be copied after they all have been collected.

Stared comments need code.

Sub SelectAllValidCells()

```
  ' select first cell

  [J15].Select

  ' Test contents of active cell; if active cell is empty, exit loop.

  Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)

     ' ***** need to figure out how to gather the valid cells 
     ' here to later copy to clipboard when we reach empty cell 

     ' Step down 22 rows to the next cell.
     ActiveCell.Offset(22, 0).Select

    ' Return to top of loop.
  Loop
  '***** copy gathered cells to clipboard
```

End Sub

Comment: Have you checked the [Union](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa213609(v=office.11).aspx) function?

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub Tester()

Dim rng As Range, c As Range

    Set c = Range("J15")

    Do
        If rng Is Nothing Then
            Set rng = c
        Else
            Set rng = Application.Union(rng, c)
        End If

        Set c = c.Offset(22, 0)
    Loop While Len(c.Value) > 0


    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        rng.Copy Range("K1")
    End If

End Sub
```